# I cant link my styles.css to my index.ejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

Im having an issue linking my css stylesheet to my index.ejs. I have my index.ejs code seperated into files like _header.ejs, _footer.ejs etc. I've also been getting a 404 error in my morgan http request logger and it read: `GET /css/style.css 404 152 - 0.537 ms` Not sure why its returning 404 error. My code for my server.js looks like this

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ejs = require("ejs")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const path = require('path')

const app=express();

dotenv.config({path:'config.env'})
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

// logs requests
app.use(morgan('tiny'));

// parse request to body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

// set view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

// load assets
app.use('/css', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/css')))
app.use('/img', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/img')))
app.use('/js', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/js')))


app.get("/", function(req, res) {

    res.render('index')
})


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
})
```

Header for my index.ejs which is stored in my _header.ejs looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Crud App</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0eca62e181.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="/" class="nav-brand text-dark">User Management System</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

also, here is my index.ejs:

```
<!-- include header -->
 <%- include('include/_header') %>
<!-- /include header -->


   <!-- Main Site -->
   <main id="site-main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box-nav d-flex-justify-between">
            <a href="/add-user" class="border-shadow">
                <span class="text-gradient">New User <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i></span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <form action="/" method="POST">
            <table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>@Email</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <%- include('include/_show') %>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>

    </div>
</main>
<!-- /Main Site -->

<!-- include footer -->
<%- include('include/_footer') %>
<!-- /include footer -->
```

and my file structure looks like:
[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QR0oz.jpg)

My stylings show up when i link it in my index.html which is the same as my index.ejs, however not separated into different files. that path is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assests/css/style.css">`. All my html show's up properly as well. Any suggestions would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

solution

```js
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require("ejs")
const app=express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
// set view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
// load assets
app.use( express.static(__dirname+'/assets/css'))//✅
app.use(  express.static(__dirname+ '/assets/img'))//✅
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render('index')
})
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
})
```

and  `index.ejs` in views folder

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div><img src="./01.jpg" alt=""></img></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

when you used `app.use( express.static(__dirname+'/public)` means by
this address(`public folder` ) has been identified for express

Comment: I tried this and still no luck. the log i get in my console from my morgan http logger is `GET /css/style.css 404 152 - 0.537 ms`. I'm not sure why im getting a 404 error though

Comment: This code correctly execute   this  is  a photo of my code  and workspace
https://ibb.co/SBSJsF3

Comment: I think  you're missing wrong about  writing address  

❌`/css/style.css`❌
✅`./style.css`✅

Comment: Thank you for the replies however it is still not displaying. I even copy and pasted in  ```./style.css``` and ```app.use( express.static(__dirname+'/assets/css'))```.  my http request logger still returns ```GET /style.css 404 148 - 1.738 ms``` so im still getting a 404 error. Also in the regular index.html file i made, the link ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assests/css/style.css"> ``` works so i must have the correct path. At this point, im tempted to just restart the app since im not too far in and can just copy and paste in most of my code.